# ActionController::RoutingError Rails and Angular

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, coffeescript, restangular

Every time ProductController is called and Restangular getting data from the rails server. I got this error

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/products.json/6862"):

I thought if product.json/:id is the route with rails it will automatically go to show view (show.json.jbuilder). Any idea what did I miss?

*ProductController.js.coffee*

```
controllers = angular.module('controllers')
controllers.controller("ProductController", [ '$scope', '$routeParams', '$location','Restangular'
  ($scope,$routeParams,$location,Restangular)->

    Restangular.one('products.json', 6862).get().then (c) ->
        console.log c
        $scope.content = c
    return
])
```

*routes.rb*

```
TindaIo::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root 'home#index'
  resources :products, only: [:index, :show]
end
```

*show.json.jbuilder*

```
json.product do
  json.title @product.title
end
```

Comment: I believe that tryin' to access `/products.json/6862` cannot actually works. If you try to access that url using something like postman, is that works? You should try to access `/products/6862.json`

Comment: @El-Key I have solve this problem by renaming show.json.jbuilder to show.jbuilder and just use Restangular.one('products', 6862).get().then (c) -> ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve this problem by renaming show.json.jbuilder to show.jbuilder and just use Restangular.one('products', 6862).get().then (c) -> ...